# Android Retrofit 2 synchronous call

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I need to the synchronous call to refresh the Auth token, but I got '**NetworkOnMainThreadException**'.

```
@Synchronized
fun refreshToken(): String? {
    val refreshToken = AuthService.getRefreshToken(context)
    var id_token: String? = null

    val call = apiService.refreshToken("refresh_token", refreshToken)
            val response = call.execute()

            id_token = response.body()

            if (id_token != null)
            {
                AuthService.saveTokens(context, id_token)
            }
        })

    return id_token
}
```

How should I do to avoid the 'NetworkOnMainThreadException'?

```
D/OkHttp: --> POST https://localhost/api/auth/refresh http/1.1 (372-byte body)
D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP FAILED: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.test, PID: 1537
                  android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                  ...
```

Comment: Synchronous calls don't cause that exception. Calling network anywhere on the main thread does. Please show a [mcve] and the full logcat

Comment: Also, not the problem, but after getting the token, this can easily be asynchronously done with `call.enqueue()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best way to implementing refreshToken with Retrofit is using Authenticator.

```
class TokenAuthenticator : Authenticator {
    override fun authenticate(route: Route?, response: Response?): Request {
        //call your Refresh Token here
    }
}
```

finally set TokenAuthenticator to your OkHttpClient

```
val httpClient : OkHttpClient.Builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
httpClient.authenticator (TokenAuthenticator())
```

if you insist on using your way you should call retrofit api in another thread